# Jquery script in Wordpress hide/show class in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Running Wordpress with jQuery. Can't seem to get this script to work.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ($('.ADShow').is(':in-viewport')) {     
      $(".ADShow").delay(6000).slideDown(4000);
    } else { 
      $(".ADShow").hide();           
    }
  });
</script>
```

The class is hidden until within viewport. Then, when in viewport, a 6-second delay reveals the class div. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Explain it better. Are you getting any error or something on the console log?

Comment: No errors. Simply not working. The class should be hidden by default and only displayed(aft delay) when in viewport (scrolling down - just below the fold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , with animation and some extra function for determining div is in view or not

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


  var  animated = false;
  var element = $('.ADShow');
    curHeight = element.height();// taking height of div 
    element.css('overflow','hidden');// hiding completely
    zeroHeight = element.css('height','0px') // set height to 0 for hidiing div  

  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

 if ( isScrolledIntoView(element,true)  && animated == false) { 
     element.height(zeroHeight).delay(6000).animate({height: curHeight}, 4000); // animate

// delay  the css also 
    setTimeout(function(){
          element.css('overflow','visible'); // set back proprty to it's default value 
     },6100)//you can change value to get desirable result

     animated = true; // set to true for executing only one time 
  }  
  })


});

/*
*================ Function  for determining div is in  view or not 
*/
function isScrolledIntoView(elem, partial) {

    if (jQuery(elem).length == 0){

         return false;
    }

    var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

    var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    if (typeof partial == 'undefined' || partial == false) {
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    } else {
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom && elemBottom >= docViewTop) || (elemTop >= docViewTop && elemTop <= docViewBottom));
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much, Artsrun. I'm going to also try Professore's approach and will return here this evening.

Comment: BTW, I did notice one caveat - the div displays for a 1/2 second, disappears and then the animate runs. Somewhat of a FOUC scenario.

Comment: Disregard: Setting  element.css('overflow','visible'); to hidden seems to have fixed that.

Comment: Good , div on document ready  event  disappear then when scrolling to it it's starting to animate ,, one note, if from beginning div in viewport then you additionally need to trigger scroll inside documet ready function  **jQuery(window).scroll();** , so in order to fire function

Comment: This worked perfectly  (jQuery(elem).length == 0)  i use only this one on my code thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `is(':in-viewport')` can be used like that.

Are you using a plugin like this [isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) or [jquery_viewport](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)?

I think if you used those, then you could use:
`$('.ADShow:in-viewport')` as the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is all on the first line

```
jQuery(document).ready(....
```

Your “document” is “ready” only once, when it is fully loaded, so your script is probably working, but is only running too early.

Maybe you want to check if your element is in viewport more than once, not only when your document is loaded.

You can do this in several ways:

- With an “Interval” you might check your element hundreds of times per second, until the event you are expecting happens.
- With a “Scroll” event you can repeat your controls every time your page scrolls.
- With a third party library, like [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/), you might call a function exactly when your element enters in viewport, and I bet that this is exactly what you are looking for.

Using Waypoints with jQuery you can write something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ADShow').waypoint({
        handler: function() {
            $(this).delay(6000).slideDown(4000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Professore! I'll give it a try today and will return here this evening.